# Java 8 Locale.getDefault() returning null

Tags: java

We have a case where a PC running a Java 8 application using 1.8.0_092 is returning null from `Locale.getDefault()`. While dealing with this is trivial, I'm more worried that null is being returned, since the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault--) for the method does not indicate that null is possible. We are not setting a locale from the java command line, and are not calling `setDefault()` anywhere.

What might be wrong in this installation that `Locale.getDefault()` would return null? Am I not reading Java documentation correctly?

Comment: Information about the system would be useful

Comment: Can you simply run a `public static void main(String[] args){System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());}` Can you validate that this happens in a **clean** environment? I am unable to reproduce - I strongly assume this is something specific with your runtime environment.

Comment: You can always open Java source files and put breakpoint in there and see what is going on. Open Locale source code put breakpoint in getDefault and follow the call stack.

Comment: @TsolakPetrosian this only happened on a specific client PC at this point, so installing a whole debugger and debugging it is not possible

Comment: @MattClark this only happens on a client PC and we only had an hour of access to it today before they had to return it to normal use. we can NOT reproduce this on our test infrastructure PCs. a workaround/check is easy. BUT how could the PCs environment be messed up such that it leads to getDefault() returning null? do you agree that the documentation as written suggests that null is not an expected return?

Comment: What locale is defined in the operating system of the client? For Windows, it would be region and language in the control panel, or better still systeminfo in the command window. Could it be that you have a combination that is not recognized by the version of Java you are using?

Comment: @JonathanRosenne it is a US based WIndows 7 64 bit with English language, I was not able to check the Region and Language menu on it before I left. a quick check of the language packages available for Windows verses the locales supported by Java 8 shows that Java should be able to represent any available windows language pack. testing shows only the display language affects the java Locale; the windows "Location" in the Region menu does not.

Comment: How is the display language defined on the offending computer? I had experienced various problems with client machines having random locales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at source code of JDK 1.8.0_092 I see that the value returned by `Locale.getDefault()` comes the field `defaultLocale` (Locale.java:2022).

```
private volatile static Locale defaultLocale = initDefault();
```

The `initDefault()` builds a key (`LocaleKey`) based on the variables `language`, `region`, `script`, `country` and `variant`, then search into a `Cache` object which is `LocaleObjectCache<LocaleKey, Locale>`.

Well, I don't want bother you with other details but in essence, this code is looking in a Map for an existing `LocaleKey` for the given environment so it is possible that such Locale does not exist.

Comment: This might not be the case in subsequent versions of the JDK8 line, as LocaleObjectCache will create the entry if it does not exist. You might want to revisit your answer.


```if (entry != null) {
            value = entry.get();
        }
        if (value == null) {
            V newVal = createObject(key);```